# how vusers showing in blazemeter?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have two thread groups in my jmx file. a variable with value 20 is defined with jmeter_users. Same variable using for two thread groups.
Now while I am executing the above jmx file, it is showing 1 vuser, where as I want it to show like 20 vusers.
While I am executing above scenario with one thread group, then showing 20 vusers.
So exactly not able to figure out reason to show 1 vuser in 2 thread groups scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think BlazeMeter respects your `jmeter_users` variable, the number of virtual users can be set using [**Load Configuration** area](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005911369-Load-Configuration-Load-Configuration):

[image]

So my expectation is that you will see as many "vusers" as you set under your "Load Configuration".

Also be aware that you can reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket), they should know their product much better than anyone here.